# silence rekall python library logging output

Tags: python, logging

I created the script [rekall_offset_finder.py](https://github.com/libvmi/libvmi/blob/master/tools/windows-offset-finder/rekall_offset_finder.py) which is importing the [Rekall](https://github.com/google/rekall) memory forensic framework to extract various kernel offsets from a memory dump.

I'm facing a problem with logging output, which i feel i'm not totally in control.

First of all, I had to use a small hack to remove *Rekall*'s `logging.basicConfig()` while the library is being imported, so that i can configure my own logging level:

```
    # remove Rekall basicConfig()
    for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
        logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
    # configure my logging level
    logging.basicConfig(level=log_level)
```

And now, I still get annoying output messages:

```
./rekall_offset_finder.py -u qemu:///session winxp
INFO:root:Dumping winxp physical memory to /tmp/tmpsuam8btj/tmpa30uvrc5
WARNING:root:Unable to determine file size, assuming file is volatile.
INFO:root:Autodetected physical address space Elf64CoreDump
INFO:root:Loaded profile pe from Local Cache - (in 0.0884544849395752 sec)
INFO:root:Loaded profile nt/GUID/7075F995A48A414F8F7BE9A1E0240F821 from Local Cache - (in 0.21683239936828613 sec)
INFO:root:Loaded profile nt/eprocess_index from Local Cache - (in 0.19333624839782715 sec)
INFO:root:Detected ntkrpamp.pdb with GUID 7075F995A48A414F8F7BE9A1E0240F821
INFO:root:Detected kernel base at 0x804D7000
Trying to fetch http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntkrpamp.pdb/7075F995A48A414F8F7BE9A1E0240F821/ntkrpamp.pdb
INFO:root:Loaded profile mspdb from Local Cache - (in 0.08299803733825684 sec)
```

Some of these messages are not mine.

I know i can silence them with a call to `logging.getLogger(name).setLevel(logging.WARNING)`

**->** How can I determine the name of the logger to silence ?

**-> Is there a way to list all the available loggers ?**

Thanks !

Comment: You are passing the root logger instance to the session, so all records emitted there will be handled same way as yours. Why not passing a separate logger instance with own configuration (and possibly without propagation to the root logger)? Unfortunately, the script requires too many dependencies to reproduce the error locally, so it's just a notice from reading its code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been given to me by @hoefling.

I was passing my root logger as Rekall's session logger.

By removing it, Rekall had to create it's own logger, and it had a new namespace: `rekall.1`:

```
WARNING:rekall.1:Unable to determine file size, assuming file is volatile.
```

To silence it, I used:

```
logging.getLogger('rekall.1').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

**To determine the loggers available**, you can use:

```
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys()
```

Thanks !